# populate tfs2013 global list via database

Tags: tfs

In Team Foundation Server 2013, is it possible to populate a global list via database query? I want to be able to pull down a customer list to use in a dropdown when a support person creates a new bug or task. Or does the global list need to be created manually?

Comment: No, you can't do it dynamically. Globallists are defined in a xml file called "globallist.xml" and only approach you can take is to create a scheduled job which updates the xml and upload it to the server.

Answer (score 2):

You can manipulate the global lists via TFS API. 
You'll have to use the [ExportGlobalLists](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.workitemtracking.client.workitemstore.exportgloballists.aspx) and [ImportGlobalLists](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb140395.aspx) methods.

You can't update a single global list; you'll have to export all global lists to an Xml document, find the customer list in the Xml document, update it then import the Xml document with all lists into TFS.

Comment: A follow up if you don't mind. Is there a way to query sql directly from the XML to populate a dropdown and not use a global list at all?